# using controlled vocabulary in <html><head>

Tags: html, rdfa, vocabulary

In `<body>`, controlled vocabularies may be initialized as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
  lang="en"
  xml:lang="en"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body prefix="
  bibo: http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/
  cc: http://creativecommons.org/ns#
  dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/
  foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/
  schema: http://schema.org/
">
```

Is it acceptable (and a good programing practice) to take a similar approach to using controlled vocabularies in `<head>`? For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
  lang="en"
  xml:lang="en"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>
<head prefix="
  bibo: http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/
  cc: http://creativecommons.org/ns#
  dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/
  foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/
  schema: http://schema.org/
">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<meta dc:author content="fname_lname" />
<meta schema:dateCreated content="yy-mm-dd" />
<meta bibo:Website href="http://www.example.com" />
<link foaf:Person href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/_Google_mbox_string_/about" rel="publisher" />
<title></title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `prefix` on [any element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-html-rdfa-20130822/#extensions-to-the-html5-syntax). The prefixes will apply to descendant elements; so if you specify `prefix` on `head`, you can’t use those prefixes for elements in `body`.

If you want to use the same prefixes in the whole document, you might want to use the `html` element.

Just in case you don’t know: You don’t have to specify the prefixes for vocabularies defined in the [RDFa Core Initial Context](http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1). As long as you use the registered prefixes (and you don’t define these prefixes for something else in your document), you can use `foaf`, `schema` etc. without using `prefix`/`vocab`.

Comment: TY. I was aware of the default initialization of certain CV (http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1). However, I did not know that I could assign the CVs to the html element. TY for telling me that. I conclude from your advice: initialize the CV one time. The CV term will be parsed properly where ever used BELOW the initialization.